# CSS display flex not working

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css, flexbox

I am using bootstrap and I have two elements at are col-md-6 inside a row and what I am trying to do is make both the col-md-6 equal height without setting a height. I have tried setting the row as display flex, but that didnt work, the background image at the bottom of the first col-md-6 is short in height. Here is my code.

```
<div class="row row-eq-height">
            <div class="col-md-6 upcoming-communities-info">
                <div class="col-md-12 landing-introduction padding-left container-padding-right container-padding-bottom" style="background-color: #FFF;">
                    <img src="/Images/communities/upcoming-communities/logo.jpg">
                    <h1>Coming To Soon</h1>
                    <ul>
                        <li>Point 1</li>
                        <li>Point 2</li>
                        <li>Point 3</li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-12 landing-image" style="background: url(/Images/communities/background.jpg) 0px -100px; background-size: cover;">
                    <div class="right-pull">
                        <h2>Towns &amp; Singles</h2>
                        <h1><span class="from">from<br>the</span><span class="dollar">$</span><span class="price">400's</span></h1>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6 upcoming-form">
                  <!--A massive HTML form-->
            </div>
        </div>
```

How do I get both col-md-6 the same height?

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: you're using bootstrap 3 or 4?

Comment: @MichaelCoker bootstrap 3

Comment: If you want to use `flexbox` and Bootstrap I'd use [**Bootstrap v4 Alpha**](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/), it uses `flexbox` and will create equal height columns by default.

Comment: Adding `flex` to the parent does it.... https://codepen.io/mcoker/pen/BZJdNQ

Comment: One thing to note is that you shouldn't nest cols directly, each set of cols needs to be wrapped by a row. See the docs http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-nesting. In your example `.upcoming-communities-info` has two `.col-md-12` children without a `.row` element in between.

Comment: You have invalid bootstrap syntax, using `col-md-12` inside `col-md-6`. To set `display: flex` on `row` makes the `col-md-6` have same height, though that doesn't necessarily make the child elements of `col-md-6` to behave, as they are still non flex items. If you could post an image of the expected output we might have a chance to help you out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option is to use [**Bootstrap v4 Alpha**](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/). It uses `flexbox` for the grid system and will create equal height columns by default.

```css
@import url( 'https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css' );

.row {
  color: white;
}

.row > div:first-child {
  background-image: url( 'https://unsplash.it/800/400?image=75' );
  background-size: cover;
}
.row > div:last-child {
  background-image: url( 'https://unsplash.it/800/400?image=125' );
  background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <p>
        Chase gangway starboard hail-shot Jolly Roger draught pink. Cutlass trysail broadside scuppers prow rigging nipperkin. Mizzenmast Chain Shot jolly boat prow flogging maroon clap of thunder. Scourge of the seven seas long clothes sloop tackle doubloon chase guns swing the lead.
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">

      <p>
        Chase gangway starboard hail-shot Jolly Roger draught pink. Cutlass trysail broadside scuppers prow rigging nipperkin. Mizzenmast Chain Shot jolly boat prow flogging maroon clap of thunder. Scourge of the seven seas long clothes sloop tackle doubloon chase guns swing the lead.
      </p>
      <p>
  Come about spike tack crow's nest barkadeer overhaul cackle fruit. Sink me gibbet me careen quarterdeck splice the main brace fluke. Driver spyglass scurvy lee gun jolly boat bucko. Boatswain ho yo-ho-ho gibbet dead men tell no tales knave Sail ho.
      </p>
      <p>
  Coffer reef lee belay mutiny coxswain cable. Hands bring a spring upon her cable heave down quarter Spanish Main yardarm starboard. Keel bilged on her anchor bounty take a caulk chase flogging draught. Hands scuttle Sink me killick keel matey avast.
      </p>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```